# javascript bowling game approach idea

Tags: javascript

I need to create a simple bowling game that outputs pins hit in every frame and scores in every frame, and total points.

my first approach idea is, having a "start new game" button that generates all of the randomized numbers for every frame before so that when user clicks "bowl", it outputs frame by frame from the generated array.

my second approach is generating randomized numbers every time click on "bowl" frame by frame. Although, I am quite lost how I can add bonus points when there is spare or strike.

Are these even the approach I should be taking or is there a better approach to create the bowling game in javascript?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right path to do it 'as needed'. As far as calculating strikes and spares, you'll have to evaluate the array to determine what the prior frames were.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully implement this, but this does the right thing with spares at least. I didn't want to take all of the fun away. :) Just think about how many different situations there will be. For example: 1) open frame, no preceding strikes or spares; 2) spare with no preceding strike or spare; 3) spare with preceding strike(s); 4) strike with no preceding strikes; 5) strike with preceding strike. I don't think that's inclusive, but something like that.

```
var game = [7, 5, '/', 8];

var score = 0, consecStrikes = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < game.length; i++){
  if(game[i] === 'X'){
    consecStrikes++; }
  else{
    if(consecStrikes > 0){
      // code to add strikes here 
    }
  score += game[i] === '/' ? game[i - 1] + 10 : game[i]; 
  } 
}

console.log(score);
```